# V-model gives: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: right-hand side of 'in' should be an object, got null" with computed function

Tags: vue.js

I have a Vuetify component which is toggled based on a vuex value.

Component:

```
<v-navigation-drawer
  app
  floating
  color="#F5F7F8"
  :mini-variant.sync="this.toggleMini"
  width="240"
  v-model="this.mobileToggle"
  :permanent="$vuetify.breakpoint.mdOnly"
  :temporary="$vuetify.breakpoint.smAndDown"
  v-click-outside="this.overlayToggle"
  v-if="this.setUser"
  >
</v-navigation-drawer>
```

Computed:

```
    mobileToggle() {
      if (this.$store.getters.g_mobileDrawer === !null) {
        return this.$store.getters.g_mobileDrawer;
      }
      return false;
    },
```

Store

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    miniVariant: false,
    mobileDrawer: true,
    user: false,
  },
  mutations: {
    miniToggle(state) {
      state.miniVariant = !state.miniVariant;
    },
    mobileToggle(state) {
      state.mobileDrawer = !state.mobileDrawer;
    },
    userState(state) {
      state.user = !state.user;
    },
  },
  getters: {
    g_miniVariant(state) {
      return state.miniVariant;
    },
    g_mobileDrawer(state) {
      return state.mobileDrawer;
    },
    g_user(state) {
      return state.user;
    },
  },
});
```

Workaround, because state isn't updated if I click on nav overlay. (This is also called on created)

```
    overlayToggle() {
      // workaround for close on overlay click on mobile, otherwise state isn't updated.
      if (this.$vuetify.breakpoint.smAndDown && this.mobileToggle === true) {
        this.$store.commit('mobileToggle');
      }
    },
```

It works on mobile, but if I resize the screen, or use dev tools I get: `Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: right-hand side of 'in' should be an object, got null"` on `v-model="this.mobileToggle"`.

As far as I know there's no 'in' involved. mobileToggle isn't null either, it's false.

Comment: what's the value of `g_mobileDrawer`?

Comment: your condition is wrong, you should do something like `(this.$store.getters.g_mobileDrawer !== null)`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Alright, changed that. g_mobileDrawer is true.

Answer (score 0):

Your v-model is a transformation of this:

```
:value="this.mobileToggle"
@input="this.mobileToggle = $event"
```

Your computed has no setter here.

Just modify it like that :

```
mobileToggle: {
  get(){
    if (this.$store.getters.g_mobileDrawer === !null) {
      return this.$store.getters.g_mobileDrawer;
    }
    return false;
  },
  set(newMobileToggle){
    // your action to mutate g_mobileDrawer
  }      
},
```

If you don't want the navigation-drawer to mutate g_mobileDrawer, then replace v-model by :value

Comment: There is no setter because my mutation is in my header component on the menu toggle.

Comment: Tbh i don't know if your error has a relation with the computed.

But doing this :

this.mobileToggle = $event

Should fire an error.

Have you tried to put :value instead of v-model ?

Comment: Yes, and the behaviour does not change.